# Json exporter needs to be passed the target and the json as a parameter, in prometheus configuration

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have a prometheus setup that using prometheus operator. I have configured a blackbox exporter for monitoring some urls using prometheus. Similar way, I have implemented a json exporter for getting metrics from a json url path. My configuration is as follows:

````
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    jsonpath: [$.details.db.details.hello] # Look for the nanoseconds field
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - https://URL path
  relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: [__address__]
      target_label: __param_target
    - source_labels: [__param_target]
      target_label: instance
    - target_label: __address__
      replacement: jsonexporter:9116  # Json exporter.
  metric_relabel_configs:
    - source_labels: value
      target_label:  hello``` 



But the issue is, getting error while reloading the Prometheus as follows:

level=error ts=2019-04-16T06:05:24.395218368Z caller=main.go:597 err="Error loading config couldn't load configuration (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml): parsing YAML file /etc/prometheus/config_out/prometheus.env.yaml: yaml: unmarshal errors:\n  line 3871: cannot unmarshal !!str `value` into model.LabelNames"

Cam someone help me to correct this?
````

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. Modified the configuration as follows;

````
  metrics_path: /probe
  params:
    jsonpath: [$.details.db.details.hello] # 
  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - https://URL path
  relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__address__]     # set param 'target' to the original target
          target_label: __param_target
          replacement: ${1}
        - source_labels: [__param_target]  # set label 'instance' to it as well
          target_label: instance
          replacement: ${1}
        - target_label: __address__
          replacement: jsonexporter:9116```
````